# How do I populate excel with address details from Google?

Tags: microsoft-excel, api, query, google-maps

I have a list of companies in Column A in excel. I have been manually googling each company and copying and pasting the address into Column B, but there must be a better way?

Here's what I've tried so far:

I created a Concatenated Hyperlink in column B which, when clicked, opens a browser window which runs an API call on google maps to bring through the address:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=",[@Organisation],"&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address&key=XXXXXXXX"),"link")
```

I still have to click the link and copy and paste the result, there must be a way that this API could just run automatically against all organisations in column A (formatted as [@Organisation] in the query as that is the table column name) and populate the result into column B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a formula, if you are running under Windows with the `FILTERXML` and `WEBSERVICE` functions, you could use:

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE(CONCATENATE("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml?input=",[@Organization],"&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address&key=xxxxx")),"//formatted_address")
```

[image]

If you don't have those functions, you could use string functions to parse the json or xml string.